# Xcode prompts repository locked while adding swift packages

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

While trying to add swift package manager xcode is prompting the repository is locked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAbRF.png)

Using xcode 11.5

- I am able to commit on git

Things already tried:

- Restarted computer
- Delete index.lock & HEAD.lock
- Delete podlock

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Which package dependency are you trying to add to  your Xcode project ?

Comment: Adding tcn client. Tried adding swifty json also

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I am able to add the package using the below steps, To add a package dependency to your Xcode project, select File > Swift Packages > Add Package Dependency and enter its repository URL. (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git) for Swifty JSON

Comment: Ya works for every one but fails for me might be an issue with git